# keep array order when getting values from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For input of `var idx = [4, 6, 5]`:

```
i: 0 id: 4 rating: 999
i: 2 id: 5 rating: 333
i: 1 id: 6 rating: 666
```

Desired result:

```
i: 0 id: 4 rating: 999
i: 1 id: 6 rating: 666
i: 2 id: 5 rating: 333
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": 22
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "rating": 999
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "rating": 333
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "rating": 666
  }
];

var idx = [4, 6, 5];

$.each(data, function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < idx.length; ++i) {
    if (idx[i] == this.id) {
      console.log('i: ' + i + ' id: ' + this.id + ' rating: ' + this.rating);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Swap the two loops.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not even think of this! @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem solves by `Array.map` Just map your idx values:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": 22
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "rating": 999
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "rating": 333
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "rating": 666
  }
];

var idx = [4, 6, 5];
var mappedData = idx.map(function(idx) {
  return data.find(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.id === idx
  })
})
mappedData.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log('id: ' + v.id + ' rating: ' + v.rating);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You were just looping with the wrong list :)

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": 22
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "rating": 999
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "rating": 333
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "rating": 666
  }
];

var idx = [4, 6, 5];

idx.forEach((id, index) => {
  const myData = data.find(x => x.id == id);
  console.log(`i:${index} id:${myData.id} rating: ${myData.rating}`)
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": 22
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 111
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "rating": 999
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "rating": 333
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "rating": 666
  }
];

var idx = [4, 6, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < idx.length; i++) {
  const rating_ind = data.findIndex(e => e.id == idx[i])
  if (rating_ind > -1) {
    console.log('i: ' + i + ' id: ' + idx[i] + ' rating: ' + data[rating_ind].rating);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to include a short description of what you changed, why it works etc.